# Save a dataframe to a new csv file in a new directory

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I am trying to take some new data that I have created from some old data and I want to save the new data in a different directory separate from the original directory from where I got the original data. I believe I have the correct data path but I don't think I am using the correct method being called to both create the csv and put it in the newly created directory. I have the code what I was suggested:

```
#create the appropriate data path
datapath = '../data'
#save the dataframe as a csv file in a new directory
save_file(ski_data, 'ski_data_cleaned.csv', datapath)
```

I get an error:
NameError: name 'save_file' is not defined

I was understanding the 'save_file' was the method and I'm not sure how to include the 'datapath' in other methods?

Answer (score 2):

try below one:
Call to_csv method on your dataframe. you need to pass the CSV file path as an argument for the method.

```
ski_data.to_csv("../data/ski_data_cleaned.csv")
```

If you need to save without headers then use the following one.

```
ski_data.to_csv("../data/ski_data_cleaned.csv", header=False, index=False)
```

To save a specific location

```
#For windows
ski_data.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\data\ski_data_cleaned.csv")
```

Check out the [official site](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for more details.